# keep image faded when rollover text/link

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/L43ec/
trying keep image faded when rollover on text/link

```
<div class="overlay">
  <div id="hover"></div>
</div>

<div class="pic_info"><a href="#">blah</a></div>



$('.overlay, #hover_small').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).find('#hover, .overlay_small, .pic_info').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, function() {
    $('.pic_info').fadeIn();
  });
});

$('.overlay, #hover_small').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.pic_info').fadeOut(300);
    $(this).find('#hover, .pic_info').stop().delay(100).animate({opacity: 1,}, function()     {
  });
});
```

Comment: Not usre if this will help but you may want to look into jQuery [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move pic_info to inside the overlay div then stop fading it out/in at specific points, it works.

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div id="hover"></div>
    <a href="#"><div class="pic_info"><h4><i><u>Motion</u></i></h4><h2>'CREO' Experimental Short</h2></div></a>
</div>
```

and

```
$('.overlay, #hover_small').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).find('#hover, .overlay_small').stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, function () {
        $('.pic_info').fadeIn();
    });

});

$('.overlay, #hover_small').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $('.pic_info').fadeOut(300);
    $(this).find('#hover').stop().delay(100).animate({
        opacity: 1,
    }, function () {

    });
});
```

the main issue was when you hovered over the pic_info, you were leaving the overlay, thus causing it to fade out. By making it a child of the overlay, hovering over it no longer does anything.